# .NET C# unsafe/fixed doesn't pin passthrough array element?

Tags: c#, arrays, unsafe, value-type

I have some concurrent code which has an intermittent failure and I've reduced the problem down to two cases which seem identical, but where one fails and the other doesn't.

I've now spent way too much time trying to create a minimal, complete example that fails, but without success, so I'm just posting the lines that fail in case anyone can see an obvious problem.

```
Object lock = new Object();

struct MyValueType { readonly public int i1, i2; };
class Node { public MyValueType x; public int y; public Node z; };
volatile Node[] m_rg = new Node[300];

unsafe void Foo()
{
    Node[] temp;
    while (true)
    {
        temp = m_rg;
        /* ... */
        Monitor.Enter(lock);
        if (temp == m_rg)
            break;
        Monitor.Exit(lock);
    }

#if OK                                      // this works:
    Node cur = temp[33];
    fixed (MyValueType* pe = &cur.x)
        *(long*)pe = *(long*)&e;
#else                                       // this reliably causes random corruption:
    fixed (MyValueType* pe = &temp[33].x)
        *(long*)pe = *(long*)&e;
#endif

    Monitor.Exit(lock);
}
```

I have studied the IL code and it looks like what's happening is that the Node object at array position 33 is moving (in very rare cases) despite the fact that we are holding a pointer to a value type within it.

It's as if the CLR doesn't notice that we are passing *through* a heap (movable) object--the array element--in order to access the value type. The 'OK' version has never failed under extended testing on an 8-way machine, but the alternate path fails quickly every time.

- Is this never supposed to work, and 'OK' version is too streamlined to fail under stress?
- Do I need to pin the object myself using GCHandle (I notice in the IL that the *fixed* statement alone is not doing so)?
- If manual pinning is required here, why is the compiler allowing access through a heap object (without pinning) in this way?

*note: This question is not discussing the elegance of reinterpreting the blittable value type in a nasty way, so please, no criticism of this aspect of the code unless it is directly relevant to the problem at hand.. thanks*

[edit: jitted asm]
Thanks to Hans' reply, I understand better why the jitter is placing things on the stack in what otherwise seem like vacuous asm operations. See [rsp + 50h] for example, and how it gets nulled out after the 'fixed' region. The remaining unresolved question is whether [cur+18h] (lines 207-20C) on the stack is somehow sufficient to protect the access to the value type in a way that is *not* adequate for [temp+33*IntPtr.Size+18h] (line 24A).

[image]

[edit]

#### summary of conclusions, minimal example

Comparing the two code fragments below, I now believe that #1 is not ok, whereas #2 is acceptable.

(1.) The following **fails** (on x64 jit at least); GC can still move the **MyClass** instance if you try to fix it *in-situ*, via an array reference. There's no place on the stack for the reference of the particular object instance (the array element that needs to be fixed) to be published, for the GC to notice.

```
struct MyValueType { public int foo; };
class MyClass { public MyValueType mvt; };
MyClass[] rgo = new MyClass[2000];

fixed (MyValueType* pvt = &rgo[1234].mvt)
    *(int*)pvt = 1234;
```

(2.) But you **can** access a structure inside a (movable) object using *fixed* (without pinning) if you provide an explicit reference on the stack which can be advertised to the GC:

```
struct MyValueType { public int foo; };
class MyClass { public MyValueType mvt; };
MyClass[] rgo = new MyClass[2000];

MyClass mc = &rgo[1234];              // <-- only difference -- add this line
fixed (MyValueType* pvt = &mc.mvt)    // <-- and adjust accordingly here
    *(int*)pvt = 1234;
```

This is where I'll leave it unless someone can provide corrections or more information...

Comment: I think my question might boil down to the details of the 'fixed' statement. What does it actually guarantee, and what gets put into the IL code as a result? Should I see explicit calls to GCHandle.Alloc in the IL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Modifying objects of managed type through fixed pointers can results in undefined behavior
>  (C# Language specification, chapter 18.6.)

Well, you are doing just that.  In spite of the verbiage in the spec and the MSDN library, the *fixed* keyword does not in fact make the object unmoveable, it doesn't get pinned.  You probably found out from looking at the IL.  It uses a clever trick by generating a pointer + offset and letting the garbage collector adjust the pointer.  I don't have a great explanation why this fails in one case but not the other.  I don't see a fundamental difference in the generated machine code.  But then I probably didn't reproduce your exact machine code either, the snippet isn't great.

As near as I can tell it should fail in both cases because of the structure member access.  That causes the pointer + offset to collapse to a single pointer with a LEA instruction, preventing the garbage collector from recognizing the reference.  Structures have always been trouble for the jitter.  Thread timing could explain the difference, perhaps.

You could post to connect.microsoft.com for a second opinion.  It is however going to be difficult to navigate around the spec violation.  If my theory is correct then a read could fail too, much harder to prove though.

Fix it by actually pinning the array with GCHandle.

Comment: Fantastic reply, thanks. I just came back to my post after starting to realize that the GC needs to snoop for live references on the stack, and the above code is not exposing them. I think the reason for the immediate failure is that the array version has a lot more instructions in the unprotected gap as it checks for index out of range. That there are only 3 instructions--plus luck--may be allowing the other one to work.

Comment: btw, fwiw I was testing release builds on gcServer (8-way x64)

Comment: @Glenn, @Hans: I'm a bit confused... this is from the specs: "For each address computed by a fixed-pointer-initializer the fixed statement ensures that the variable referenced by the address is not subject to relocation or disposal by the garbage collector for the duration of the fixed statement. For example, if the address computed by a fixed-pointer-initializer **references a field of an object** or an element of an array instance, the fixed statement guarantees that the containing object instance is not relocated or disposed of during the lifetime of the statement." So shouldn't this work?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, check my re-edited conclusion from a moment ago with the new code snippets; I now believe that the #2 example should work--indeed this is the purpose of 'fixed.' As for whether #1 should work or not, it seems to be an open question, but for whatever reason--perhaps the speculation I mentioned--it doesn't on x64.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I could agree with that.

Comment: The CMP instruction it generates is quite mysterious.  But I do think it is either an issue with the C# spec not making the fixed target restricted enough or the C# compiler not falling back to pinning where required.

Comment: The sentence you cite from the C# spec is a bit vague. Does the .NET array primitive `T[]` count as an "object of managed type" if `T` is blittable? That can't be what they mean, because it would render `fixed` useless. So I'd think it's referring to those non-blittable managed types--which "fixed" won't even allow, thus mooting the statment. You seem to take it as a 3rd option, i.e. blittable-object-referring **field** of an "object of managed type," but that seems far from the words that are actually there. and even so, that field (`mvt` in my OP) is not being (as it *does* say) "modified".

Answer (score 0):

Puzzling over this, and I'm guessing here, it looks like the compiler is taking &temp (fixed pointer to the tmp array) then indexing that with [33]. So you're pinning the temp array, rather than the node. Try...

```
fixed (MyValueType* pe = &(temp[33]).x)
    *(long*)pe = *(long*)&e;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it gives the same result; still crashes right away.