# Will fixed on an address of an element in an array pin the whole array or just the element?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
fixed(byte* ptr = &myBuffer[23])
{
    ...
}
```

Will myBuffer be pinned (so I can safely do pointer arithmetic in the fixed block so long as I don't exceed the length of the array) or will only the byte at index 23 be pinned?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589945/net-c-sharp-unsafe-fixed-doesnt-pin-passthrough-array-element ? Also: pointer arithmetic in c# ... *shudder*. ^_^;

Comment: Ask yourself what it would mean if the rest of the (unpinned) array was moved whilst you had your pointer, and then some other piece of code tried to access `myBuffer[23]`.

Comment: @Corak Saw that though this is a different scenario. No problem doing pointer arithmetic in C# esp with buffers, yummy yum yum :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever could be undefined.. actually I think the whole array can move and the CLR just updates your pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C# language specification version 5.0, section 18.6:

> For example, if the address computed by a fixed-pointer-initializer references a field of an object or *an element of an array instance*, the fixed statement guarantees that the *containing object instance* is not relocated or disposed of during the lifetime of the statement

*My emphasis*

(Which was pointed to by looking at the [`fixed` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN)