# c# fixed region optimizations

Tags: c#, fixed, region

Can't find anything about this but if I find code like this

```
fixed(Foo* foo=bar) {
  doSomething(bar); // not foo
}
```

where *foo* isn't referenced, can I be certain that *bar* is kept fixed within the region and not gone due to optimization?

Comment: Eh, is it really **C#**, not, say, **C** or **C++**?

Comment: looks like C# to me https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx

Comment: I can't see any point of a fixed `bar` without using the pointer `foo` (unless the point is to make the garbage collector a bit less efficient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. That's the whole point of the `fixed` statement, as also noted in the specification:

> For each address computed by a *fixed-pointer-initializer* the fixed statement ensures that the variable referenced by the address is not subject to relocation or disposal by the garbage collector for the duration of the fixed statement. For example, if the address computed by a *fixed-pointer-initializer* references a field of an object or an element of an array instance, the fixed statement guarantees that the containing object instance is not relocated or disposed of during the lifetime of the statement.

In your case, the *fixed-pointer-initializer* is `bar`. For grammar reasons, the declaration of `foo` is needed, however. That's probably the reason for this idiom where the array `bar` has to be unmovable, but you don't really need the pointer.

One side note: It's not optimization that can move `bar` away from it's memory location outside of such a `fixed` statement. It's the garbage collector compacting the heap to ensure that it's no longer fragmented. I wouldn't call that an optimization, though.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. From googling part of the specs, I stumbled over this post which seems to differ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589945/net-c-sharp-unsafe-fixed-doesnt-pin-passthrough-array-element
It explains that the fixed region does not pin the object but inserts an offset that the GC can alter. This sounds crazy - can it be verified somewhere in the .NET docs or similar?

Comment: That's a different case, though, if I see correctly. They're trying to pin a property of a struct which is contained in an array, which seems to make things go weird.